# What is best practice for instantiating a variable for use outside of a loop if you are only assigning to it within the loop?

Tags: python, loops, scope

I frequently find myself in situations where I want to assign to a variable based upon the outcome of some comparison or other logic. I've done some Googling and I know that I CAN assign `None` to a variable and then assign to it later, but I just want to know if that's really the best way.

Here is an example of what I have in mind:

```
def function(v1, v2):
    least = None
    if v2 < v1:
        least = v2
    else:
        least = v1
```

Something in my mind is telling me there must be a better way, but I definitely wouldn't call myself an expert in Python.

Comment: You don't need to do it if you assign the variable in both `if` and `else`. But if there are some branches that might not assign it, the simplest solution is to assign the default first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't write the first assignment since it's immediately overwritten and the code's guaranteed to take one of the two branches.

```
def function(v1, v2):
    if v2 < v1:
        least = v2
    else:
        least = v1
```

You can shorten it to a one-liner if you like.

```
def function(v1, v2):
    least = v2 if v2 < v1 else v1
```

It's a matter of taste whether this is better or worse than the previous version. I like it, but it quickly becomes unreadable as the logic gets more complicated.

Comment: Thank you, I was being super dense and for some reason was conflating If/Else with an actual Loop, so I was thinking I would get a scoping issue if I declared inside the If/Else!

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to assign it first in your example, because all branches of the condition assign it.

Assigning a default value first is necessary if there could be code paths that don't assign the variable. A common situation is if you assign the variable in a loop; if the loop executes zero times, you won't set the variable.

```
def function(lst):
    result = None
    for item in lst:
        if somefunc(item):
            result = item
    return result
```

If you don't initialize `result` before the loop, you'll get an error if the list is empty or none of the elements satisfy the `somefunc()` condition.

Comment: And so in this example, I SHOULD say `result = None` or some other default value, right?

Comment: Right. I was showing the erroneous code that needs the initialization added to it.